# C++ Previous Record Gets deleted when writing a new object

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to save an Object from a class. When I add a new Record (Add a new object being saved) the previous records becomes deleted. What am I doing wrong? It seems that once I add a new object the one that was created previously gets deleted because idk. Been trying this for hours. can't seem to figure it out.

```
void Department2File(HANDLE screen, Department &Departments, int deptcount)
{
    Department Testing;
    fstream file;
    file.open("Departmentsdata.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    file.close();
    file.open("Departmentsdata.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file.";
    }

    // writting data
    long size = (deptcount * sizeof(Departments));

    if (deptcount == 0)
    {
        size = (deptcount * sizeof(Departments));
    }
    else
    {
        size = (deptcount * sizeof(Departments))+1;
    }

    cout << "\nsaved!" << endl;;
    file.clear();
    file.seekp(size, ios::beg);
    file.write(reinterpret_cast <char *>(&Departments), sizeof(Departments));
    file.clear();
    file.seekg(size, ios::beg);
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&Testing), sizeof(Departments));


    cout << Testing.DepartmentID;////////////<--------------delete

    ///////////////////////////////
    ///////////////DELETE//////////
            file.clear();
            file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
            file.get(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&Testing), sizeof(Departments));
            cout <<"\n RECORD 0: "<<Testing.DepartmentID;

                                    ////////////////////////////
    file.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the flag `ios::app` in the `open` function to add the output at the end of the file:

`file.open("Departmentsdata.dat", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);`

Check this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

**UPDATE**: Try to use just one open in your code:

```
fstream file;
file.open("Departmentsdata.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
file.close();
file.open("Departmentsdata.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

like this:

```
fstream file;
file.open("Departmentsdata.dat", ios::in | ios::app | ios::out | ios::binary);
//Write Something
file.close();
```

But it depends of what you are trying to do.